# restFixture LET for text/plain

Tags: javascript, rest, text, let

is there any way to parse plain text in restFixture? If so, a simple example will be much appreciated.

Ex: If the response contains (x=abc) as plain text, I would like to manipulate the text and set it to a variable using the let verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

You can use a javascript adapter for that.

Ex: let | varname | js | response.body | |

Reference: https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixture/issues/26

Thanks!

Comment: Many more examples are available in the RestFixureLiveDoc module here https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixtureLiveDoc/blob/master/src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/RestFixtureTests/LetTestsV2/content.txt